# the subscription is not purchased through the app, but on a website?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

Are there any examples of iPhone or iPad apps that allow downloads from a subscription business, where the subscription is not purchased through the app, but on a website?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Eurosport app allows you to view a subscription that is purchased outside of the app store.

Same with most TV channel players.